# scrapy: issues fetching starting url to scraping amazon video info

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to webscraping. what I'm trying to do is scraping all the amazon movies from amazon website.  I went to the amazon website www.amazon.com.

I chose amazon video on the left side of search box and type in 'video' and search. I got a list of whole lots of movies. The web Url is `https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dinstant-video&field-keywords=video&rh=n%3A2858778011%2Ck%3Avideo`

Next, I I went to the scrapy shell and type `scrapy shell 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dinstant-video&field-keywords=video&rh=n%3A2858778011%2Ck%3Avideo'`
My response status is `400`.
I also tried adding user agent. `scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36' 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dinstant-video&field-keywords=video&rh=n%3A2858778011%2Ck%3Avideo'`
I still got response status ```400``.

Why that happens?
How can I find the starting Url so that I can start scraping all the movie info?

I have no clue how to deal with it. I truly appreciate it if anyone can help.Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I tried **scrapy shell "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dinstant-video&field-keywords=video&rh=n%3A2858778011%2Ck%3Avideo"**   and i got a 503, then I use command **view(response)** to see what happened on the page. The Amazon gives me [verification code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJvUW.png) to verify if I'm a robot.

So I entered your second scrapy shell command with User-Agent set, and I got [200 response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSGTp.png)

Maybe you could try using **view(response)** and see what you got there, or you could try scrapy shell for a few more times?

Comment: @ la_vie_est_belle    thank you so much. Yes, I tried it again and now it works!  A follow up question , on amazon website, whenever I type, e.g. smart phone in the search box, I just cannot get any response. Do you know why? for example try this url:  
 https://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_pg_1?fst=as%3Aon&rh=k%3Asmart+phone%2Cn%3A2335752011%2Cn%3A7072561011&keywords=smart+phone&ie=UTF8&qid=1517020683

Comment: I don't quite get your point, but it seems no sense that you can't get any response. Could you post your codes or steps so that I can see what you want to do?

Comment: can you try this? I got 400 error:                       scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36' 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref\=sr_pg_1\?fst\=as%3Aon\&rh\=k%3Asmart+phone%2Cn%3A2335752011%2Cn%3A7072561011\&keywords\=smart+phone\&ie\=UTF8\&qid\=1517020683'

Comment: Actually i got 200 when i try https://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_pg_1?fst=as%3Aon&rh=k%3Asmart+phone%2Cn%3A2335752011%2Cn%3A7072561011&keywords=smart+phone&ie=UTF8&qid=1517020683   but not the one from your last comment. Is there any typo in the url from your last comment?

Comment: I know what is going on. When I copy and paste the url from the browser to my zsh, it automatically added a lot of '\'s. (as shown in my last comment).  I have no idea why! If you happen to know what happened, please let me know.  when I switch to bash shell, everything is fine.  thank you so much!

Comment: well, i don't know about zsh, but I'm glad that the problem is solved. :)